# Add our JSON data center in google map api

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

i get lat and lng position from database .i replace it in center JSON but he doesn't work. console position giv me `{lat:31.752809648231494,lng:-7.927621380715323}` 
and i convert it to json

```
 {lat: "31.752809648231494", lng: "-7.927621380715323"}
```

what i can do to remove double quote in json date i think is the error

```
var pos = position.replace(/\"/g, "");
          console.log(pos);//{lat:31.752809648231494,lng:-7.927621380715323}
          var json = JSON.parse(position);
          console.log(json); //{lat: "31.752809648231494", lng: "-7.927621380715323"}


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 31.791702, lng: -7.092620000000011},
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
```

Comment: Is what you are getting from your database the **string** `"{lat:31.752809648231494,lng:-7.927621380715323}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing double quotes from JSON string will also remove the quotes wrapping the keys, which will turn it into an invalid JSON, and that's why `JSON.parse` will fail.

Instead, you can try `JSON.parse` on the original object and use `parseFloat` to convert the string values to equivalent numbers.

```
center: {lat: parseFloat(json.lat), lng: parseFloat(json.lng)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i try this method but without using parseFloat but now is working tk-u